# Name for the argument of the mathematical absolute-value function

Tags: terminology, mathematics

Some arguments of common mathematical functions have names, like [addend](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/addend), [minuend](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minuend), [subtrahend](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subtrahend), [dividend](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dividend), [divisor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divisor), [numerator](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/numerator), [denominator](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/denominator), and [radicand](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/radicand).

A colleague recently asked me:  does the argument of the absolute-value function have its own name of this sort?

Answer (score -2):

As stated on [this webpage](https://www.cuemath.com/calculus/modulus-function/) and on [this one](http://www.mathsmutt.co.uk/files/mod.htm) the **absolute value** of a number is its **modulus** and the symbol |x| is referred to as "modulus x".

This can be confusing because *modulus* is used in computing for the remainder of division, that is the result of the *modulo* function where the result ignores the number of times the divisor goes into the numerator. In computing these functions are usually called by using something like MOD(x,y) and ABS(x) but in maths |x| is called the **modulus** of x.

Comment: The \*output\* absval of x, |x|, can be called "[the ]modulus[ of] x" but that doesn't say what x itself should be termed with respect to the operation (or if even there is something to designate the object 'x' as the operand of | |). Only for nonnegative real values of x is the modulus_of x equal to [the input value ]x.

Comment: As @11qq00 correctly [says](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/575518/name-for-the-argument-of-the-mathematical-absolute-value-function/575525#comment1434951_575525), I am looking for a name for the *input*, not the output, of the absolute-value function.